# How to encode url, containing special characters in query parameters using resttemplate

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, urlencode, spring-resttemplate

I am getting error when I hit a URL which contains special characters in query parameters using RestTemplate.

My URL is something like this

```
 https://someendpoint?q=countryCode:(AB+yz)&q=type.code:12345&q=banner.code:A1&q=openDate[*+TO+NOW%2B3MONTH]%20&q=!date:[*+TO+NOW]
```

Can someone please help me how to encode such type of URL using RestTemplate.
This URL works fine when I hit through Browser or Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the StringHttpMessageConverter.

```
  RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
  template.getMessageConverters()
    .add(0, new 
StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
 ResponseEntity<Object> response = template.exchange(endpoint, method, entity, 
                                                Object.class
```

Comment: Its still giving error.
It says 500 internal server error (most probably url encoding error.)

Comment: @AamirSheraz: Have you tried this 
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParam("msisdn", msisdn)
        .queryParam("email", email)
        .queryParam("clientVersion", clientVersion)
        .queryParam("clientType", clientType)
        .queryParam("issuerName", issuerName)
        .queryParam("applicationName", applicationName);